# How to hide parameter from url, when need to pass data from one page to another?

Tags: laravel, routes

Instead of showing **../product/1**

```
$breadcrumbs->push($name,url('/product/'.$id));
```

I want it to be displayed as **../product**

Any method can be used to do this ?

Comment: what is `$breadcrumbs`? is it a library?

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden input field like:

```
<input name="id" value="{{$id}}" hidden>
```

Not a too good practice, But you can hide `id` parameter from `url`